# How to get the div id's of this form?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, ecmascript-5

Working on an app that exports what the user typed on the app to a particular website with the similar components. For example, if the user typed a title on the app, when he presses a button, it imports that value to a webpage which also requests the user to type.

This is the flow chart or something

User --> User inputs a text in the app --> App copies what the user's typed --> App opens a particular website --> App pastes what he copied to the website.

(Website: A google form for an example.)

Now I've already finished all of it except for the latter part where the app pastes what he copied.

The problem is the app do not know where to paste it.

So I want to get the ID's of the code below, it is perfectly fine if you just identify all the id's or something similar and how to call it.

Have imported data from backend successfully, but have zero clue on how to get the id's or the variable names of a textarea, radio buttons, the div.

javascript:

```
(function () {
function WW(ele, val)
{
    if(document.getElementById(ele) && val != "")
    {
        document.getElementById(ele).value = val;
    }
}
WW("story-title", "The Good Peacock");
)();
```

Copied this from someone.

This works with other sites that have the an id, like:

```
<textarea id="story-title">
```

So, need to know the id's of the `HTML` below.

This is a part of the source code of the website, which is auto-fill.

Tried calling with `getElementByClassName()`, but didn't work.

```html
    <form class="main-edit-form">

          <div class="required-form-wrapper">
            <div class="form-group title-form">
              <label>Title</label>
              <span class="empty-warning hidden" id="title-warning">Required</span>
              <div contenteditable="true" class="story-title">Untitled Story</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group description-form">
              <div class="form-wrapper">
                <label>Description</label>
                <span data-toggle="popover" class="popover-icon" id="description-tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Add a story description"><span class="fa fa-info fa-wp-lightergrey " aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:16px;"></span></span>
                <span class="empty-warning hidden" id="description-warning">Required</span>
              </div>
              <textarea type="text" name="title" class="story-description "></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group tags-form">
              <div class="form-wrapper">
                <label>Tags</label>
                <span data-toggle="popover" class="popover-icon" id="tags-tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Help readers find your story"><span class="fa fa-info fa-wp-lightergrey " aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:16px;"></span></span>
                <span class="empty-warning hidden" id="tag-empty-warning">Required</span>
              </div>
              <div class="tag-container">
                <div id="editable-tags">
                  <div class="component-wrapper" id="component-TagGrid-storyTags-/myworks/new"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="add-tag" class="tag-item with-icon on-add-tag">
                  <span>Add a tag</span><span class="fa fa-plus fa-wp-black " aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:12px;"></span>
                </div>
                <span id="tag-input-wrapper">
                <input id="tag-input" class="hidden on-tag-input" placeholder="Separate tags with a space" autocomplete="off">
              </span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group inline-form">
              <div class="form-wrapper">
                <label for="categoryselect">Genre</label>
                <span data-toggle="popover" class="popover-icon" id="category-tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Tell Wattpad the genre of your story"><span class="fa fa-info fa-wp-lightergrey " aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:16px;"></span></span>
                <select id="categoryselect" class="form-control ">
                  <option value="-1">Select a genre</option>
                    <option value="14">Action</option>
                    <option value="11">Adventure</option>
                    <option value="24">ChickLit</option>
                    <option value="6">Fanfiction</option>
                    <option value="3">Fantasy</option>
                    <option value="21">General Fiction</option>
                    <option value="23">Historical Fiction</option>
                    <option value="9">Horror</option>
                    <option value="7">Humor</option>
                    <option value="8">Mystery / Thriller</option>
                    <option value="16">Non-Fiction</option>
                    <option value="12">Paranormal</option>
                    <option value="2">Poetry</option>
                    <option value="19">Random</option>
                    <option value="4">Romance</option>
                    <option value="5">Science Fiction</option>
                    <option value="17">Short Story</option>
                    <option value="13">Spiritual</option>
                    <option value="1">Teen Fiction</option>
                    <option value="18">Vampire</option>
                    <option value="22">Werewolf</option>
                </select>
                <span class="empty-warning hidden" id="category-empty-warning">Required</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="inline-form-wrapper">
            <div class="inline-form-row">
              <div class="form-group inline-form">
                <div class="form-wrapper">
                  <label>Language</label>
                  <span data-toggle="popover" class="popover-icon" id="language-tooltip" title="" data-original-title="What language is your story in?"><span class="fa fa-info fa-wp-lightergrey " aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:16px;"></span></span>
                  <select id="languageselect" class="form-control ">
                      <option value="1" selected="selected">English</option>
                      <option value="2">Français</option>
                      <option value="3">Italiano</option>
                      <option value="4">Deutsch</option>
                      <option value="5">Español</option>
                      <option value="6">Português</option>
                      <option value="38">Català</option>
                      <option value="19">Tiếng Việt</option>
                      <option value="18">Filipino</option>
                      <option value="20">Bahasa Indonesia</option>
                      <option value="22">Bahasa Melayu</option>
                      <option value="32">ภาษาไทย</option>
                      <option value="7">Русский</option>
                      <option value="15">Română</option>
                      <option value="23">Türkçe</option>
                      <option value="24">Česky</option>
                      <option value="14">Polski</option>
                      <option value="28">Magyar</option>
                      <option value="30">ελληνικά</option>
                      <option value="35">Eesti</option>
                      <option value="36">Latviešu</option>
                      <option value="37">Lietuvių</option>
                      <option value="39">Босански</option>
                      <option value="40">Српски</option>
                      <option value="41">Hrvatski</option>
                      <option value="43">Български</option>
                      <option value="44">Slovenčina</option>
                      <option value="42">Slovenščina</option>
                      <option value="45">Беларускі</option>
                      <option value="46">Українська</option>
                      <option value="26">Svenska</option>
                      <option value="27">Norsk</option>
                      <option value="34">Suomi</option>
                      <option value="29">Dansk</option>
                      <option value="13">Nederlands</option>
                      <option value="33">Íslenska</option>
                      <option value="12">简体中文</option>
                      <option value="8">繁體中文</option>
                      <option value="9">日本語</option>
                      <option value="10">한국어</option>
                      <option value="16">العربية</option>
                      <option value="53">ગુજરાતી</option>
                      <option value="17">עברית</option>
                      <option value="21">हिन्दी</option>
                      <option value="25">മലയാളം</option>
                      <option value="54">ଓଡ଼ିଆ</option>
                      <option value="31">فارسی</option>
                      <option value="55">ਪੰਜਾਬੀ</option>
                      <option value="56">অসমীয়া</option>
                      <option value="47">বাংলা</option>
                      <option value="48">اُردُو&lrm;</option>
                      <option value="49">தமிழ்</option>
                      <option value="50">Kiswahili</option>
                      <option value="51">Afrikaans</option>
                      <option value="57">मराठी</option>
                      <option value="11">Other</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group inline-form copyright-form">
                <div class="form-wrapper">
                  <label>Copyright</label>
                  <span data-toggle="popover" class="popover-icon" id="copyright-tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Who owns your story?"><span class="fa fa-info fa-wp-lightergrey " aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:16px;"></span></span>
                  <select id="copyrightSelect" class="form-control ">
                      <option value="0">Not Specified</option>
                      <option value="1">All Rights Reserved</option>
                      <option value="2">Public Domain</option>
                      <option value="3">Creative Commons (CC) Attribution</option>
                      <option value="4">(CC) Attrib. NonCommercial</option>
                      <option value="5">(CC) Attrib. NonComm. NoDerivs</option>
                      <option value="6">(CC) Attrib. NonComm. ShareAlike</option>
                      <option value="7">(CC) Attribution-ShareAlike</option>
                      <option value="8">(CC) Attribution-NoDerivs</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group rating-form">
              <div class="form-wrapper">
                <label class="rating-label">Rating</label>
                <span data-toggle="popover" class="popover-icon" id="rating-tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Rate your story"><span class="fa fa-info fa-wp-lightergrey " aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:16px;"></span></span>
                <span class="toggle-prompt">Mature</span>
                <div class="onoffswitch ">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="mature-switch">
                  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="mature-switch">
                    <div class="onoffswitch-inner">
                      <span class="on">ON</span>
                      <span class="off">OFF</span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

These `id`'s you are looking for are not generated by them self.

You need to assign `id` to field that you like.

I don't prefer to use `id` to implement `css`. Element `id` is only to be needed to implement `javascript` and fetch there value example from `input` tag.

You need to assign `id` while writing down your code like in following sample `html`.

**Point to note**:

1. Not all tags have `id`.
2. Mostly tags related to user input have `id`.
3. No 2 elements / tag have same `id`.
4. `id`'s of different type of elements are used for different purpose, like `<div>`, `<span>` `id`'s are used for show-hide, where as `input` `id`'s are used for fetching value.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/app.css" />
        <link rel="icon" href="logo.jpg" />
        <title>Info</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="btn btn-primary form-control" onclick="showForm('#addInfo')">Add Detail</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="btn btn-primary form-control" onclick="showForm('#showInfo');getDetail();">Show Detail</p>
            </div>
            <!-- No need for `form` as will use JavaScript for Single Page Application -->
            <div id="addInfo" class="hide">
                <div id="data"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="addEmail">Email:</label>
                    <input id="addEmail" class="form-control" type="email">
                    <span id="addEmailError" class="hide error">Valid Email Required</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="addFname">First Name:</label>
                    <input id="addFname" class="form-control" type="text">
                    <span id="addFnameError" class="hide error">Valid First Name Required</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="addLname">Last Name:</label>
                    <input id="addLname" class="form-control" type="text">
                    <span id="addLnameError" class="hide error">Valid Last Name Required</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="addPhone">Phone:</label>
                    <input id="addPhone" class="form-control" type="text">
                    <span id="addPhoneError" class="hide error">Valid Phone Required</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="addGender">Gender:</label>
                    <select id="addGender" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select:</option>
                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                        <option value="female">Female</option>
                    </select>
                    <span id="addGenderError" class="hide error">Gender Required</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <p class="btn btn-primary form-control" onclick="addInfo()">Submit</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- No need for `form` as will use JavaScript for Single Page Application -->
            <div id="showInfo" class="hide">
                <div id="showDetails" class="col-md-12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- `login.js` is only used in `login.ejs` -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/addInfo.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/getInfo.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/service.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`addInfo.js`:

```
"use strict";

function addInfo() {
    // JavaScript uses `id` to fetch value
    let email               = $("#addEmail").val(),
        fName               = $("#addFname").val(),
        lName               = $("#addLname").val(),
        phone               = $("#addPhone").val(),
        gender              = $("#addGender").val();

    // Show error `span` when email is invalid
    if ( validateEmail(email) ) {
        $("#addEmailError").addClass("hide");
    } else {
        $("#addEmailError").removeClass("hide");
        return;
    }

    // Show error `span` when First Name is invalid
    if ( validateFname(fName) ) {
        $("#addFnameError").addClass("hide");
    } else {
        $("#addFnameError").removeClass("hide");
        return;
    }

    // Show error `span` when Last Name is invalid
    if ( validateLname(lName) ) {
        $("#addLnameError").addClass("hide");
    } else {
        $("#addLnameError").removeClass("hide");
        return;
    }

    // Show error `span` when Phone is invalid
    if ( validatePhone(phone) ) {
        $("#addPhoneError").addClass("hide");
    } else {
        $("#addPhoneError").removeClass("hide");
        return;
    }

    // Show error `span` when Gender is invalid
    if ( validateGender(gender) ) {
        $("#addGenderError").addClass("hide");
    } else {
        $("#addGenderError").removeClass("hide");
        return;
    }

    // Calling local API to set authentication
    // Everything in public is visible for hackers
    // Thus to hide auth calling local backend
    $.ajax({
        "url": "/v1/detail",
        "method": "POST",
        "data": {email, fName, lName, phone, gender}
    })
    .then( result => {
        // On success empty all the input fields.
        $("#addEmail").val('');
        $("#addFname").val('');
        $("#addLname").val('');
        $("#addPhone").val('');
        $("#addGender").val("");

        // Message to notify success submition
        alert("Successfully added user.");
        return;
    })
    .catch( err => {
        // Notify in case some error occured
        alert("An error occured.");
        return;
    });
}
```

`getInfo.js`:

```
"use strict";

function getDetail () {

    // Request to get details of all user.
    $.ajax({
        "url": "http://localhost:4000/v1/detail",
        "method": "GET"
    })
    .then( result => {
        // On success using table to display data.
        // This table is dynamic.
        let table = `<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        Details fetched successfully.
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>`;

        let headers = [];

        // Setting dynamic headers to ease work at frontend in case field changes
        for ( let key in result[0] ) headers.push(key);
        for ( let h of headers ) table += `<th scope="col">` + h + `</th>`;

        table += `          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>`;
        let i = 1;

        // Dynaic rows of table based upon headers.
        for(let row of result) {
            table += `      <tr>
                                <th scope="row">` + i + `</th>`;

            for (let key of headers) table += `<td>` + row[key] + `</td>`;

            table += `      </tr>`;
            i++;
        }

        table += `      </tbody>
                    </table>`;

        // Loading dynamic table into our static HTML page.
        $("#showDetails").html(table);
    })
    .catch( err => {
        // If error setting dynamic error
        let data = `<label class="alert alert-warning">Unable to fetch details</label>`;

        // Loading dynamic error into our static HTML page
        $("#showDetails").html(data);
    })

}
```

`service.js`:

```
"use strict";

/**
 * Common services used by all the other scripts
 * All these are generic functions
 *  
*/

// To toggle between different views
function showForm (id) {
    // Hide all views
    $("#addInfo").addClass("hide");
    $("#showInfo").addClass("hide");

    // Show the view user had clicked
    $(id).removeClass("hide");
}

// Validate Email based upon pattern
function validateEmail (email) {
    if ( email && email.match(/^([A-z0-9_.]{2,})([@]{1})([A-z]{1,})([.]{1})([A-z.]{1,})*$/) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Validate First Name based upon pattern
function validateFname (fName) {
    if ( fName && fName.match(/^([A-z]{2,})*$/) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Validate Last Name based upon pattern
function validateLname (lName) {
    if ( lName && lName.match(/^([A-z]{2,})*$/) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Validate Phone based upon pattern
function validatePhone (phone) {
    if ( phone && phone.match(/^([0-9]{10})*$/) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Validate Gender based upon pattern
function validateGender (gender) {
    if ( gender && gender.match(/^([A-z]{4,6})*$/) && (gender === "male" || gender === "female") ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have confused you with my question, I am aware that id's don't generate themselves. The website I am talking about isn't run by me therefore I cannot add the id like you asked, I just want the id of the tags that needs user input so I can get its value. And thank you for for these scripts, I may need this as a reference for my next project.